# Cannot get Ember test to fail

Tags: ember-cli, qunit

I'm very green to Ember testing, but have found a lot of useful documentation for it online so far (thank you people!).  One of the issues I'm hitting here, though, is I cannot get a test to fail.  Strange, I know.  For example, I have the following:

```
import {
  module,
  test
} from 'qunit';

module("Example tests");

test("This is an example test", function(assert) {
  assert.equal(1, 1, "Ember knows 1 is equal to 1");
});

test("This is another example test", function(assert) {
  assert.notEqual(1, 2, "Ember knows 1 is not equal to 2");
});

test("This is a 3rd example test", function(assert) {
  assert.equal(1, 2, "Luke, you're an idiot");
});
```

However, if I run the ember-cli command:  ember test
It says everything passes..

```
$ ember test
Future versions of Ember CLI will not support v0.10.38. Please update to Node 0.12 or io.js.
version: 0.2.2

A new version of ember-cli is available (0.2.3). To install it, type ember update.
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://www.ember-cli.com/#watchman for more info.
Built project successfully. Stored in "/Users/luke/Examples/iris/tmp/class-tests_dist-DYvAvX3c.tmp".
ok 1 PhantomJS 1.9 - JSHint - .: app.js should pass jshint
ok 2 PhantomJS 1.9 - JSHint - helpers: helpers/resolver.js should pass jshint
ok 3 PhantomJS 1.9 - JSHint - helpers: helpers/start-app.js should pass jshint
ok 4 PhantomJS 1.9 - JSHint - .: router.js should pass jshint
ok 5 PhantomJS 1.9 - JSHint - .: test-helper.js should pass jshint
ok 6 PhantomJS 1.9 - JSHint - unit: unit/ExampleTest.js should pass jshint

1..6
# tests 6
# pass  6
# fail  0

# ok
```

What am I doing wrong here???

Comment: You're not testing anything, tests have to end with a `-test.js` in order to be detected.

Comment: Thanks @Kitler !  If you want to post this as the answer I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt look to the [docs](http://www.ember-cli.com/#tests), tests need to end with a `-test.js` in order to run.